# What's the difference between f o g and f o g(x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What's the difference between $f \circ g$ and $(f \circ g)(x)$?

See http://prntscr.com/kz3zxt for a screenshot, this is clarification for a homework question.

Comment: $f \circ g$ is the function, $(f\circ g)(x)$ is the value of the function $f \circ g$ at the point $x$

Comment: This is like asking "*what is the difference between $f$ and $f(x)$.*"  $f$ is a function and $f(x)$ is the output of $x$ when the function $f$ is applied to it.

Answer (score 3):

$f \circ g$ is a map, and $(f \circ g)(x)$ is the value of this map at a point $x$.

Comment: $f \circ g$ is not a map , $f \circ g:A\to B$ is  a map (i.e. a function)

Answer (score 0):

They both indicate the [**composition**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) of $f$ and $g$ which is also indicated often as $f(g(x))$.

Sometimes we distinguish from $f\circ g$ to indicate the composite function and $f\circ g(x)$ to indicate its value at $x$ but also the latter is often used to indicate the composite function.